# What is Mifare native mode?

Tags: nfc, iso, mifare, apdu

What is Mifare native mode? And what is the difference in interaction with card between native mode commands and APDU commands from ISO/IEC 7816-4 (or ISO 14443-4)?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is almost contained in the second part of your question: Mifare native mode uses lower level commands than ISO 14443-4, so there are no APDUs to send. To access Mifare native mode, you will need hardware and software made or licensed by Mifare's owning company NXP.

For example, only mobile phones using NXP chips can use Mifare native mode to interact for example with Mifare Classic cards.